# Failed to load ruby gem, using require method in IRB

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i've created my own rubygem, but when i try in my local machine, there were something annoying, i've been around in google and another StackOverflow question but still not found the solution about this problem.

If i use non-root user in **irb** and type **require 'my_own_gem'** after type **require 'rubygems'** i've got :

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- my_own_gem
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from (null):0
```

But when using root user, with sudo irb, the problem isn't seen and everything look OK.

**gem list -d my_own_gem**

```
my_own_gem (0.0.1)
    Author: Jane Doe
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/my_own_gem
    Homepage: google.com
    Installed at: /var/lib/gems/1.8

    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

**gem env**

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

**.bashrc**

```
export GEM_HOME=/var/lib/gems/1.8
export GEM_PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8
```

**my_own_gem.gemspec**

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "my_own_gem/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "my_own_gem"
  s.version     = MyOwnGem::VERSION
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.authors     = ["Jane Doe"]
  s.email       = ["j4n3d0e@gmail.com"]
  s.extra_rdoc_files = ["MIT-LICENSE","README.rdoc"]
  s.rdoc_options = ["--charset=UTF-8"]
  s.homepage    = "google.com"
  s.summary     = %q{lorem ipsum}
  s.description = %q{lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
  s.date = Time.now.utc.strftime("%A, %d% %B %Y")
  s.rubyforge_project = "my_own_gem"

  s.add_dependency "httparty", "= 0.7.8"

  s.post_install_message = "my own gem"

  s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
  s.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]

end
```

Comment: How did you install ruby?  It sounds like the ruby you get when you're root is not the same ruby you have when you're a regular user.  `which ruby` and `sudo which ruby`.

Comment: installed from package-manager, the result from which ruby and sudo which ruby is /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: Did you sudo install your gem?

Comment: If you installed the gem with sudo, is it readable by non-root users? I don't recall if the loader will distinguish between directories it can't read and directories that don't exist. +1 on making sure that "which ruby" returns the same value with and without sudo as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try add to your .bashrc file

```
export RUBYOPT="rubygems"
```

or try to install your gem to `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/......`